# Unity section in .config file using Protected Configuration Provider

Tags: c#, unity-container, app-config, config, rsaprotectedconfiguration

In my app config I'm using RSA Protected Configuration Provider, everything works fine when using it with connectionStrings section but NOT with unity section in app.config. Whenever I try to make this call:

```
container.LoadConfiguration("MyManager");
```

I get;

```
Unrecognized attribute 'configProtectionProvider'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.
```

App.Config after encryption:

```
<unity configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
...
```

what gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I was missing this after the save:

```
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sectionName);
```